# How to get back pointer of pointers from a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a function which open a file, read its content line by line and then push it to an array. I have managed to get the array functionnal inside the right function, but when I want to get it back to my main function, I cannot get any items of my array.

Some code will help you to understand:

My main function:

```
/* ----------------- MAIN ------------ */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    /*... some useless code for now ... */

    char **ptrLines = NULL;
    ptrLines = readEventFile(ptrParam, ptrLines);
    outputExecTrace(WAR, "PTRLINES x : %x", ptrLines);
    outputExecTrace(WAR, "PTRLINES char[] : %s", *(ptrLines + 2));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My fileReader function:

```
char** readEventFile(Parameters *parameters, char **arrLine) {

    FILE *fp = fopen(parameters->inputFilePath, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(0);

    char line[128];
    int nbCharOfLine = 0;
    while(1) {
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
        if (feof(fp))
            break;

        nbCharOfLine++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    arrLine = malloc(sizeof(line) * nbCharOfLine);
    nbCharOfLine = 0;
    fp = fopen(parameters->inputFilePath, "r");
    while(1) {
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
        if (line[0] != '#') {
            arrLine[nbCharOfLine] = malloc((strlen(line)+1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(arrLine[nbCharOfLine], line);
            nbCharOfLine++;
        }
        if (feof(fp))
            break;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    outputExecTrace(WAR, "ARRLINE x : %x", arrLine);
    outputExecTrace(WAR, "ARRLINE char[] : %s", *(arrLine + 2));

    return arrLine;
}
```

Has it is, my outputs are the followings:

```
WARNING: ARRLINE int : -2020552688
WARNING: ARRLINE char[] : 1 3 4 //This is the result I am looking for.

WARNING: PTRLINES int : -2020552688 // Same as ARRLINE
Segmentation fault (core dumped) // And this is because ptrLines[2] doesn't contains anything... but why ?!
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Please choose a language. An answer for C will be very different to one for C++.

Comment: right now I see only one mistake `sizeof(line)` should be `sizeof(char*)`

Comment: `nbCharOfLine++;` should be before `feof` check

Comment: I advise you to remove all of this file I/O code while you concentrate on the problem of returning an array-- it's a great distraction and a hiding place for bugs.

Comment: There's no need to pass in `arrLine` as argument. The first thing you do is to allocate fresh memory to it, so it could be a local variable, whose value - a handle to heap-allocated memory - you return.

Comment: regarding this line: 'exit(0);'  1) this is the same as 'exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );'  2) this line occurs where an error is found.  suggest: 'exit( EXIT_FAILURE );'

Comment: the first while(1) loop is trying to determine the number of lines in the file.  A much easier method would be to just get the size of the file.  either using 'stat()' or using fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_END );  bytecount = ftell(fp);  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET );  after which there would be no need to close/re-open the file

Comment: always check (!= NULL) the returned value from malloc to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what happen, because you have several small problems within code, which could lead to this, try to change your code in following way:

```
char** readEventFile(char* fileName) {
    char line[128];
    int nbCharOfLine = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(1);
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        char *r = fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp); // NOTE: proper handling of fgets return value
        if ((r != NULL) && (line[0] != '#'))
            nbCharOfLine++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    char **arrLine = calloc(nbCharOfLine, sizeof(char*)); // use calloc to be sure
    nbCharOfLine = 0;

    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        char *r = fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
        if ((r != NULL) && (line[0] != '#')) {
            arrLine[nbCharOfLine] = calloc(strlen(line) + 1, sizeof(char));
            strcpy(arrLine[nbCharOfLine++], line);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return arrLine;
}
```

in your main, you will call this function like:

```
char **ptrLines = readEventFile(ptrParam->inputFilePath);
```

Comment: @user3629249 can you elaborate?

Comment: using 'feof()' as a loop control is (almost) always not correct.  however, keeping the definition of the array local is much better than passing it to the function.

Comment: Using feof() for loop control (it is still false when the end of the file is reachedl) means an extra iteration through the loop, where the fgets() will fail.  the suggested code does handle that problem, but using the fgets() for the loop control, rather than feof() means the problem never arises.

Comment: @user3629249 ah, you mean this, yeah, you're right, EOF flag is set only after read, I've just tried to re-use original code as much as possible

Comment: I admit that your function is proper than mine, but the result still the same. ptrLines still having the good ref to the array but it doesn't have any references to the array's items. BTW I'll keep that in mind ;)

Comment: @Jagaia I've tested this code and it works as expected, probably you have error somewhere else in your code

Comment: My bad, it is working very well, I just forget an include. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure this is the whole problem, but the posted code:

```
while(1) {
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
    if (line[0] != '#') {
        arrLine[nbCharOfLine] = malloc((strlen(line)+1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(arrLine[nbCharOfLine], line);
        nbCharOfLine++;
    }
    if (feof(fp))
        break;
}
```

is not the right approach for several reasons, 
including that function feof()
is only asserted 'true' when the code has tried to read past the
end of the file.

suggest:

```
while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) )
{
    if (line[0] != '#') 
    {
        if( NULL == (arrLine[nbCharOfLine] = malloc((strlen(line)+1) * sizeof(char)) ) )
        { // then, malloc failed
            perror( "malloc failed" );
            // close file and free all malloc'd areas
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, malloc successful

        strcpy(arrLine[nbCharOfLine], line);
        nbCharOfLine++;
    }
}
```